# Get List inside List

Tags: elm

I have a complex data structure and I had to create this short example for better understanding.

```
type alias People = 
  { name : String
  , sex : String
  , phones : List Phone
  }

type alias Phone =
  { number : String
  , isActive : Bool
  }
```

This structure populated:

```
people = [
  { name = "_me"
  , sex = "M"
  , phones = [
    { number = "(99) 99 9 9999-9999"
    , isActive = True
    }]
  }, 
  { name = "_you"
  , sex = "M"
  , phones = [
    { number = "(11) 11 1 1111-1111"
    , isActive = True
    },
    { number = "(22) 22 2 2222-2222"
    , isActive = False
    }]
  }]
```

And I would like to get only the 'phones' from the 'people' list, as in the example below

```
phones = [
  { number = "(99) 99 9 9999-9999"
  , isActive = True
  },
  { number = "(11) 11 1 1111-1111"
  , isActive = True
  },
  { number = "(22) 22 2 2222-2222"
  , isActive = False
  }]
```

I've been trying for 3 days, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull out all the phone numbers into a list by mapping over to get the phone number list of a person, then concatenating those phone number lists together:

```elm
getPhones : List People -> List Phone
getPhones = List.concat << List.map .phones
```

Comment: Or `List.map .phones >> List.concat`

Comment: Many thanks @Chad, I feel bad that you have solved the problem in 1 line.

Comment: Nothing to feel bad about! Keep at it and the conciseness of the functional style will grow on you

Comment: Or `List.concatMap .phones` :)

Comment: Should not this work? `List.concat (List.map .items)`

Comment: No, @GuilhermeEscarabel, that will not work. My original answer used currying, so you could rewrite it like this: `getPhones people = List.concat (List.map .phones people)`